# Simple graph connectivity when minimum degree is $\geq \frac{n-1} {2}$

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

Essentially the title, but we had to prove that the simple graph is connected. I know the standard way of doing this by assuming two components and then contradiction. But i wanted to know about another approach that i used:
Since we know that tree has $n-1$ edges and minimum edges in our case would be $\frac{n(n-1)}{4}$ and if I assume that our graph has more edges than a tree than we get $n\geq4$. Also by the formula of maximum edges in a graph with k components, $\frac{(n-k)(n-k+1)}{2}$ and comparing it with our graph for $k=2$, we get $n\leq4$. Now I know that trees are minimal connected and so this approach might not be entirely correct but I am unable to find any counter examples. So kindly help me with a counter example or simply help me to make this proof more rigorous or justifiable. Thank you!

Comment: By taking the ceil on minimum degree, you can improve your bound for minimum number of edges and discard $4$

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Your proof is correct.  For $n=4$, you have a min degree of 2,  so at least 3 edges, it suffices to terminate the proof

Comment: Sorry, I mean at least 4 edges

Comment: So I can use trees to compare? Because my professor says otherwise. I wanted to argue with him on this so I needed a mathematical proof

Comment: Also is there a better way to justify my answer, what I argued was we are basically adding more edges to a tree hence it will be connected...can this be improved?

Comment: In fact, I misunderstood your argument, showing that a graph has more edges than a tree is not sufficient to show that it is connected (take a clique with a disconnected vertex, it has a lot of edges but is still disconnected) but knowing that you have more than 4 edges, combined with the bound for a graph with $k$ components solve for $n=4$, so the this bound is sufficient in itself to solve the problem.